# Java Robot class failed to show popup from html select drop-down when mouse press

Tags: java, html

I am using a JAVA Robot Class to mouse move, press, keyboard operate for checking a website. In my case HtmlUnit or Selenium api is not preferred. Robot class works well until I found it failed to show popup from html select drop-down when I press mouse by robot.

Suddenly popup comes and gone immediately. I need to show popup of html drop-down by using Robot class. Any Solution?

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(778, 572);
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

[image: This Html select dropdown won't show popup when make a key through robot class]

Comment: Sometimes the programs are too fast - so maybe try putting a delay between `Press` and `Release`.

Comment: sorry @recraman i am trying delay from 100 to 10000 in different way still no hope, delay is not may be fact here. even for single press without realease cause for Suddenly popup comes and gone immediately. I don't know what cause here to hide popup.